# Entities to keep a company logo, copyrights, trademarks, patents, legal disclaimer

Tags: database, data-modeling

I am not certain how to physically data model a company logo, trademark, patents, legal disclaimer, terms and conditions etc...

If the direction is to store the aforementioned in a relational database where I already have the company as a "party" (aka an organization) and using the defitions on https://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2010/08/12/trademark-copyright-and-logos/ ,
I am thinking about an entity called "IntellectualProperty" to keep trademark, logo, patents etc... which are basically blobs or documents.
Now the disclaimer is generally a statement that is included in all documents. Each company will have its Intellectual properties so we will have to create an associative table between the organization and the IntellectualProperty.

Is it a good idea to keep the disclaimer on the "intellectualProperty" or on a separate table?

I'd like to hear your comments.  Thank you much in advance.

Comment: I think it's ok to keep the disclaimer in 'intellectualProperty'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this any way you want.  The following advice is based on normalizing your data.

If there is one disclaimer per company, keep the disclaimer in Party so you only have to update it one place when it changes.

If there is one per type of Intellectual Property, keep it in an association between Party and Intellectual Property Type.

Keep it in Intellectual Property if the disclaimer cannot be determined by Party and Intellectual Property Type.  E.g., when there is a separate disclaimer for each and every patent, logo, etc.